# Move part to bottom layer without mirroring in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, surface-mount, pcb-layers

How can I move a SMD part in Eagle to the bottom layer without using mirror?
The resulting PCB should have the SMD pads on the bottom layer but mirrored (if you turn the PCB and look on it from top view) so that the SMD part does ***NOT*** fit on it.

Comment: Make a new footprint is the obvious solution.

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?